# dplyr: omit rows with negative values conditional on two duplicated parameters per row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say I have the following stored in `p`

```
           los       tti  ID
1  1.002083333 23.516667  84
2 -0.007638889  2.633333 118
3  0.036805556  2.633333 118
4  0.134722222  2.716667 120
5  2.756250000 82.800000 132
6  1.066666667 17.933333 156
7 -2.496250000 12.830948 156
```

I want to `filter` out rows with negative values for `p$los`, but only if `p$tti` and `p$ID` are duplicated between the rows. E.g., row `2` and `3` are duplicated on both `p$tti` and `p$ID`, and therefore should row 2 be omitted due to negative value in `p$los`.
Row `6` and `7` are duplicated in regards to `p$ID`, but not `p$tti`, and should therefore stay.

I am looking for a solution in `dplyr`

```
p <- structure(list(los = c(1.00208333333333, -0.00763888888888889, 
                            0.0368055555555556, 0.134722222222222, 2.75625, 1.06666666666667, 
                            -0.00763888888888889, 4.84305555555556, 1.79375, 8.55694444444444
), tti = c(23.5166666666667, 2.63333333333333, 2.63333333333333, 
           2.71666666666667, 82.8, 17.9333333333333, 1.31666666666667, 69.2666666666667, 
           52.9833333333333, 36.0166666666667), ID = c(84L, 118L, 118L, 
                                                       120L, 132L, 156L, 179L, 245L, 253L, 334L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Depending on your measure, you may want to round your `tti` column (decimal) to some tolerance level as part of data processing. Using `dplyr` you could try something like `p %>% group_by(tti, ID) %>% filter(n() == 1 | los >= 0)` ... this would filter/keep rows where there are no duplicates by `tti` and `ID`, and then if duplicates exist, keep those where `los` is positive or zero (not negative)...would that work?

Comment: Yes, consider posting as answer - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your measure, you may want to round your `tti` column (which is a numeric decimal) to some tolerance level (e.g., 3 decimal places) as part of data processing.

Using `dplyr` you could try something like:

```
p %>% 
  group_by(tti, ID) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1 | los >= 0)
```

This would filter/keep rows where there are no duplicates by `tti` and `ID` (`n() == 1)` for the group), and then if duplicates exist, keep those where `los` is positive or zero (not negative).

**Output**

```
       los   tti    ID
     <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1  1.00    23.5     84
2  0.0368   2.63   118
3  0.135    2.72   120
4  2.76    82.8    132
5  1.07    17.9    156
6 -0.00764  1.32   179
7  4.84    69.3    245
8  1.79    53.0    253
9  8.56    36.0    334
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "           los       tti  ID
1  1.002083333 23.516667  84
2 -0.007638889  2.633333 118
3  0.036805556  2.633333 118
4  0.134722222  2.716667 120
5  2.756250000 82.800000 132
6  1.066666667 17.933333 156
7 -2.496250000 12.830948 156", header = T)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter((sd(tti, na.rm = T) + los) > 0 | is.na(sd(tti, na.rm = T))) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>       los   tti    ID
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1  1.00   23.5     84
#> 2  0.0368  2.63   118
#> 3  0.135   2.72   120
#> 4  2.76   82.8    132
#> 5  1.07   17.9    156
#> 6 -2.50   12.8    156
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>